# Using Sparkle Updater with download hosted on GitHub

Tags: cocoa, ssl, download, certificate, github

I'm hosting my downloads on GitHub, to save bandwidth on my own server, but when Sparkle updater tries to download updates from GitHub, it fails with error:

```
Sparkle Error (continued): The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)
```

I figured out that this is due to a certificate mismatch from GitHub, as you can see from this attempt to use `wget` to download my app from GitHub:

```
$ wget http://github.com/downloads/chetan51/sidestep/Sidestep%20v0.2.1.zip
--2010-11-21 16:29:26--  http://github.com/downloads/chetan51/sidestep/Sidestep%20v0.2.1.zip
Resolving github.com... 207.97.227.239
Connecting to github.com|207.97.227.239|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://github.com/downloads/chetan51/sidestep/Sidestep%20v0.2.1.zip [following]
--2010-11-21 16:29:27--  https://github.com/downloads/chetan51/sidestep/Sidestep%20v0.2.1.zip
Connecting to github.com|207.97.227.239|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name `*.github.com' doesn't match requested host name `github.com'.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you’re not actually getting as far as the certificate error. I had a similar error this weekend, and found that Sparkle (incorrectly) performs %-escaping on attachment URLs. If you change the %20 to a plain space, you’ll probably get a different error indicating the problem you thought you were having.

Not really very helpful, I know.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I changed the %20 to a space, and it worked. Thanks!